# GO: try to append to a slice of structs and write it to a JSON file, but only the last struct is being written

Tags: go, struct, slice

my file structure is like

```
├── cmd  
│   ├── a.go
│   ├── b.go
│   ├── c.go
│   ├── root.go
```

in `a.go` i have

```
type item struct{
     Name1 string
     Name2 string
}

type Data []item

func (d *Data) Add(name1 string, name2 string) {
    data := item{
        Name1:     name1,
        Name2:     name2
    }
    *d = append(*d, data)
}

func (d *Data) Save(filename string) error {
    data, err := json.Marshal(d)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return ioutil.WriteFile(filename, data, 0644)
}
```

in my`root.go`, I put

```
const (
    JsonFile = ".file.json"
)

var SomeData = &Data{}
```

and in `b.go` and `c.go` both have a function like

```
function b or c (cmd, args []string) {
   SomeData.Add(two strings)
   err = SomeData.Save(JsonFile)
}
```

I am trying to append to a slice of structs and write it to a JSON file, but only the last struct is being written in the JSON, when i tried to print the slice, the slice always has only one element inside, which is the last one. I don't know what's going on, I want to make it save all the structs I add

Comment: problem is not in this part of your code

Comment: Could you please elaborate it?

Comment: Hey! First, if even printing only displays one item in the slice, the problem isn't related to Cobra at all. Second, I tested to add two items to a `Data` object, and it worked just fine, including the marshaling to JSON. So there's probably something wrong with how you set up and modify your `Data` `d`. I didn't downvote your question, but I'ld advise you to rewrite it totally. Remove the Cobra part, show how you're creating with `d`. Your file structure also doesn't matter, just put everything you need for demonstration in a single file.

Comment: Thank you, i ve removed the Cobra part, as for the `d`, i just `var SomeData = &Data{} ` and use `SomeData.Add(two strings)
   err = SomeData.Save(JsonFile)` like i said in the post, and it isnt working, I will try to look into that

Comment: Have a look [here](https://go.dev/play/p/K8ly3aTNnby) - everything works fine. You could take this example and just refine it until your problem re-appears. Then, provide this minimal reproducable example of the error here.

Comment: Thank you for your examples, i tried a little bit, it indeed works in playground, but when i move to cobra, it just didn't work, for more details, i created a repo on this question, i used a.go, b.go , c.go in [testRepo](https://github.com/TeaACC418/Test/tree/main/awesomeProject/cmd), if you try to run this, then only the latest one will be printed

Answer (score 2):

After a glance at your example repo it looks like you're creating different commands, and each of them only calls `Add` only a single time. You need to understand what a command does: it runs the executable in separate instance. This executable does its stuff and terminates. There's no memory state shared between different executable runs - therefore, `var SomeData = &Data{}` will result into a new variable for each command.

If you want to persist the state (here: `SomeData`), you need to store it when the program terminates (you're doing that part, more or less), but you also need to restore the memory state, so you need load that data at the beginning of each run:

```golang
func (d *Data) Save() {
    data, err := json.Marshal(d)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = os.WriteFile("myFile.json", data, os.ModePerm)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

// each command must call that first.
func (d *Data) Load() {
    content, err := os.ReadFile("myFile.json")
    if err != nil {
    // You should probably handle the case that the file doesn't exist yet - I skip this part
        panic(err)
    }
    err = json.Unmarshal(content, &d)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Be aware that this might cause  issues if you run to many of those calls at the same time, all of them reading and writing at once.

As an alternative, if you want an process actively waiting for new requests to add something to the list, you can't achieve that with CLI. Instead, set up a (HTTP) server which processes requests asking it to add new values to the list (which should be managed with a lock to avoid concurrency issues). But that's beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and explanation, especially that 'it runs the executable in separate instance.' part and the last part, i did not know about this, it's my bad for forgetting to add readfile first, anyways, really appreciate it!